# Would a question of real life ways to quantify certain stats be welcome here?

Tags: discussion

If I were to ask a question involving 35 different stats, ( as Grip, Endurance, Courage, Deduction, Savvy, Flattery, and Aim) and how to quantify them using real-life tests, would such a question be accepted here?

If not, where would it be better accepted?

Comment: I have a feeling there might be a form of this question that could work on the RPG StackExchange. Tabletop players, GMs, and game system architects tend to devote a lot of thought to the meaning and role of each character stat

Comment: Keep in mind that asking about _35_ items will most likely give weird answers: some will focus on some of these stats, while some others will focus on other stats, and there is a high chance of no one covering all of the stats. This is why we generally avoid questions asking about multiple things. You might want to reduce the scope to a few of these stats, specifically the ones you have the most trouble with.

Comment: I agree with @AlexandreVaillancourt - the # of things being asked about is too large. Unless there's some criteria that categorically ties them together, (i.e. they're all on the Meyers-Briggs test, or ROTC fitness eval, etc) it strikes me as being automatically too broad on the basis of # of items alone.

Answer (score 1):

If you literally asked that, no.

If you asked a question about quantifying them in order to solve a specific problem in the context of your game, and you provide enough information about how the mechanics of your game work with those statistics, that's probably okay.

In general, we welcome game design and game mechanics questions, but because they can be *extremely* broad and discussion-based (due in no small part to their reliance on the entirely subjective concept of "fun"), we generally want such questions to provide as much context about the gameplay interactions being discussed so that answers can be as objective as possible with the context of the specific game.

Comment: Where can I put my question instead?

Comment: @Piomicron I'm not sure; what is the context of your question if it isn't game mechanics?